# How to fix position of layout in a view in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, alignment

I am adding a filter in Git repo page and modified the class `RepositoryView`. I just mentioned this so that you can find this code online if needed. My question is more of a generic alignment issue.

after i added this new filter as a 
 this is how it git repo view looks like on load after this change
[image: on load]

after maximizing the view it looks like this. here the alignment is going wrong. and the filter tool bar comes at the center.

[image: maximize]

and there after if i minimize it, the filter toolbar vanishes from the view. 
[image: minimize]

code changed

```
public void createPartControl(Composite aParent) {
        Composite displayArea = new Composite(aParent, SWT.NONE);
        displayArea.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        displayArea.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL,6));


        final Composite temp = new Composite(displayArea, SWT.FILL);//XXX

        layout = new StackLayout();
        temp.setLayout(layout);
        createEmptyArea(temp);

        super.createPartControl(temp);

        IWorkbenchWindow w = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
                .getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
        ICommandService csrv = (ICommandService) w
                .getService(ICommandService.class);
        Command command = csrv
                .getCommand("org.eclipse.egit.ui.RepositoriesLinkWithSelection"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        reactOnSelection = (Boolean) command.getState(
                RegistryToggleState.STATE_ID).getValue();

        GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).applyTo(temp);//XXX
//      GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).applyTo(displayArea);//XXX
        filterToolbar = new FilterToolbar(this, displayArea);
        IWorkbenchSiteProgressService service = (IWorkbenchSiteProgressService) getSite()
                .getService(IWorkbenchSiteProgressService.class);
        if (service != null) {
            service.showBusyForFamily(JobFamilies.REPO_VIEW_REFRESH);
            service.showBusyForFamily(JobFamilies.CLONE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could try resetting the perspective: Window > Reset Perspective. And how is the code relevant to the alignment?

Comment: @aly I actually want to fix the position of the filter box at the bottom of the view. so that when i maximize the view or minimize the view it gets aligned to the bottom

Comment: Can you see the filter box at the bottom via scrolling down? In the third image where the filter box is missing, there is a scroll bar available. Do you see the filter bar by scrolling down?

Comment: The filter box is actually out of the scrollable area. So, the only time i can view the filter is in the 1st view (on view load) or image. And once i expand it the `repo view scroll area` pushes it down, and i have to maximize the view to see filter box

Comment: Check if the tree has some minHeight set on it (in GridData), this might be forcing the tree to take up enough space that the filter box is getting clipped out.

Comment: @WaqasIlyas i had happened to correct the issue by changing min height and also many fill commands. basically i had done it hard way by checking what happens on changing every parameter in `GridData` and `Composite`. but somehow got it working today :). thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @WaqasIlyas had mentioned i was trying parameters in `GridData` mostly today and happened to get that working as you said

```
public void createPartControl(Composite aParent) {
        Composite displayArea = new Composite(aParent, SWT.FILL);
        displayArea.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        displayArea.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL,GridData.FILL, true, true));
        Composite historyComposite = new Composite(displayArea, SWT.NONE);

        layout = new StackLayout();
        historyComposite.setLayout(layout);
        historyComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_FILL,GridData.VERTICAL_ALIGN_FILL, true, true));
        createEmptyArea(historyComposite);

        super.createPartControl(historyComposite);

        IWorkbenchWindow w = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
                .getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
        ICommandService csrv = (ICommandService) w
                .getService(ICommandService.class);
        Command command = csrv
                .getCommand("org.eclipse.egit.ui.RepositoriesLinkWithSelection"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        reactOnSelection = (Boolean) command.getState(
                RegistryToggleState.STATE_ID).getValue();
//XXX added this code and changed the position of some statement to make it work
        GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).applyTo(historyComposite);
        filterToolbar = new FilterToolbar(this, displayArea);
        ((GridData) filterToolbar.getLayoutData()).verticalAlignment = SWT.END;
        Point computeSize = filterToolbar.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT);
        ((GridData) filterToolbar.getLayoutData()).minimumWidth = computeSize.x;
        ((GridData) filterToolbar.getLayoutData()).minimumHeight = computeSize.y;
        GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).align(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL).applyTo(displayArea);
//xxx code change ends
        IWorkbenchSiteProgressService service = (IWorkbenchSiteProgressService) getSite()
                .getService(IWorkbenchSiteProgressService.class);
        if (service != null) {
            service.showBusyForFamily(JobFamilies.REPO_VIEW_REFRESH);
            service.showBusyForFamily(JobFamilies.CLONE);
        }
    }
```